# How can I be sure whether my CPU is fried or not?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, desktop-computer, heatsink

So my dear friend was supposed to change my CPU while I'm away. Apparently, he wanted to test the PC without putting back the heat sink. The terrible thing is, he did it with both CPUs :_(

He says the computer very quickly shut itself, so he's "sure" that the CPUs are fine. However, I tried booting the PC with both CPUs (with heat sink fixed and thermal paste applied); I get a black screen in both cases.

Unfortunately, I don't have any extra parts to test or extra PCs to test these parts. **Is there any way for me to determine which parts are working and which are not?** Unfortunately, I don't have spare parts to do A/B testing or an extra PC to test my current parts.

When the PC is turned off but plugged into the Power Source, the LEDs of my MOBO and the GPUs are working. When the PC is turned on, both my main cooler fan and the fans of the GPUs start working. Also, I suppose the heat sink is working as the thermal paste was spread evenly across the CPU surface. Hence, I assume the MOBO is fine as well.
**Am I correct in my assumptions?**

In case it helps, here's my setup:

- ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming MOBO
- Intel i7-7700K and i5 6400
- 2 * GTX 970 ASUS Turbo(aka SLI)
- 32GB (4*8GB) DDR4-2800 ADATA XPG
- 700W Standard 80 PLUS Bronze

Comment: Have you tried reseating the CPUs themselves? First inspect all the pins in the socket to make sure none of them are bent.

Comment: @Bob Yes, a bunch of times. Now my suspicions are starting to lean towards to MOBO. Please check my response to the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Am I correct in my assumptions?**

Almost certainly.

**Is there any way for me to determine which parts are working and which are not?**

Not with the constraints you set.

Someone in your vicinity needs to buy a new i7.

Comment: I've just noticed that DRAM led is solid red. I haven't added, changed my RAM setup and had been running this for a while.

I've taken them all out, and put all four one by one into A1 slot and boot the system with a single stick. Still the led is on.

I hardly assume that I may have fried all 4 sticks. Any guesses?